# open function not returning file descriptor

Tags: python

Python open function does not return file descriptor. Why could this be? I am using python 3.3.

test_file_open.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    html = ""
    hmtl_fd = open("ns_temp.html",'r')
    for line in html_fd:
        html += line
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_file_open.py", line 7, in <module>
    for line in html_fd:
NameError: name 'html_fd' is not defined
```

Permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 michael michael 160 Mar 16 23:03 test_file_open.py
```

Comment: Please read your program once again and make sure your variable names match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in a variable name, see `hmtl_fd` and `html_fd`.

Replace:

```
hmtl_fd = open("ns_temp.html",'r')
```

with:

```
html_fd = open("ns_temp.html",'r')
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo: `hmtl_fd` in place of `html_fd`

Comment: Jeez... time to go to bed.

Comment: @user1505520 pay attention to timing next time.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/how-should-we-deal-with-duplicate-answers